# A Recipe Database Model Advice

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to design a snackbar automation system (to answer the first question - No, it's not a homework, it's for learning purposes) and I have an issue with with the recipes and how to present them in the database. I have two options:

**Option 1:**

```
[Ingredients] -> [IngrID, IngrName]
[Recipe] -> [RecipeID, RecipeName]
[IngRecipe] -> [IngrID, RecipeID]
```

In this case the third table is a typical many-to-many table, the model looks correct and it's a piece of cake to manipulate with the data using Entity Framework. But I want to keep track of the amounts as well. Generally I use Ingredients as a table to insert the new purcheses. If the ingredient exist, just update the amount.

**Option 2**

Now if I add column "amount" as a column to IngRecipe, the whole idea of many-to-many table vanishes and I no longer can use the entity model to fill the fields automatically. But I can't seem to find a more apropriete place for this column. Where and how will I say "Well, get me 100 gr of chicken breast and add it to whatever recipe"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `the model looks correct and it's a piece of cake to manipulate` Can you clarify if this database is to be used for dessert recipes only?

Comment: No, not only. I meant it is really easy to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a solid model start, consider:

```
RecipieIngredients -> Recipe (FK), Ingredient (FK), IngredientQuantity
                      Key over (Recipe, Ingredient)
```

Note that it is *still* a M-M relationship (the quantity is not part of the PK nor involved in a FK), just with more relevant data *for this relationship pair*. The names can be changed, but at some point, this *must* be represented as a M-M relationship in a normalized relational model.

Don't let the framework ruin a good normalized design - and I hope EF can cope with such trivial scenarios; even LINQ2SQL can.

Comment: Well, yes and now...That table does seem to logical place for the Amount column but then i lose the pure M-M relationship. Let me explain what I mean. If we say we don't have any amoun column, just PK, FK columns.
I could do something like:

Recipe r= new Recipe();
Products product = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == whatever ID I got from the form);
r.Products.Add(product);

Comment: If I add the amount, then EF adds the M-M table, since it doesn't see as a pure junction table anymore and I can't access the Ingredients from the Recipe model.
r.Products.Add(product); is no longer available. I don't think I should do manually the update in every single table because that is just stupid